# Get Previous dropdown on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to get the value from previous drop down value, i use this below code to get the value but it seems doesn't works.

Value 1

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#notification_id select').change(function () {
            var selLang = $(this).val();
            console.log(selLang);
            $.ajax({   
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Bnotifications/ajax_notif_languange", 
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: "notification_lang="+selLang, 
                dataType: "html", 
                beforeSend: function(data) {
                            $('#notiflang').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/template/images/loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                        },                        
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#notiflang').html(data);

                },
            })
        });
    });
```

ajax that i want to get the value

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        $('body').on('change','#notiftitle select',function () {
            var selTitle = $(this).val();
            var selLang = $("#notiflang").val();
            console.log(selTitle);
            $.ajax({   
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/Bnotifications/ajax_notif_message", 
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: "notification_title="+selTitle+'&notification_lang='+selLang, 
                dataType: "html", 
                beforeSend: function(data) {
                            $('#notification_message').html('<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/template/images/loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                        },                        
                success: function(data) {

                    $('#notification_message').html(data);

                },
            })
        });
    });
```

i use this value and put on code above, but it seems not getting the value from value 1, how to get the value from previous ajax dropdown.

```
var selLang = $("#notiflang").val();
```

Comment: is the value of the previous dropdown added dynamically?are you sure it is added before you get the value?

Comment: @guradio yes it already shown on my dropdown, but i confuse how to get the previous value, i use on above but it's got blank values....